# .NET Interop and TR1 shared_ptr

Tags: interop, pinvoke, tr1

How is it possible to marshal a shared_ptr from unmanaged C++ code into C#?

I have a function in C++ (exposed through C bindings) that will allocate a new MyObject and return a pointer to it via a shared_ptr.

In C++ I can call the function:

```
MyObjHandle* ref = NULL:
GetMyObject(&ref); // double ptr...
```

where MyObjHandle is defined:

```
typedef struct obj_t {

   shared_ptr<MyObject> objPtr;

} MyObjHandle ;
```

How would I PInvoke the call to GetMyObject from C#? I did the obvious of just defining the structure MyObjectHandle pretty much as is in C# expcept I defined the member objPtr as an IntPtr. That failed miserably with a AccessViolationException error. Tried a couple other PInvoke variations which also failed. I can't seem to find any interop samples with shared_ptr and C#. Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You can only retrieve the MyObjHandle as an IntPtr in C#. You will never have access to the internal objPtr within the structure. The pinvoke signature should look like:

// adjust return type as needed
[DllImport(...)]
int GetMyObject(out IntPtr pMyObjHandle);

You can then pass the pMyObjHandle back into any other pinvoke methods expecting a MyObjHandle* as the parameter.